# Building a list with a parent-child dependency

Tags: python, parent-child

I have a list of dicts that looks something like this:

```
list = [{'parent': u'#5963','id': 5962},{'parent': u'','id': 5963}, 
{'parent': u'#5963', 'id': 5964}, {'parent': u'#5966', 'id': 5967}, 
{'parent': u'#5963','id': 5966}, {'parent': u'#5962','id': 5968} ]
```

The actual dicts are a bit more complex - they have more keys and values.

As you can see - every dict has a 'parent' key, which tells us elements parent's id and an 'id' key.

Now the question is: is it possible to build a new list (or sort this one) in a way that all dicts are placed in a parent-child way?

So the new dict will be:

```
[{'parent': u'','id': 5963},{'parent': u'#5963','id': 5962}, 
{'parent': u'#5962','id': 5968}, {'parent': u'#5963', 'id': 5964},
{'parent': u'#5963','id': 5966}, {'parent': u'#5966', 'id': 5967} ]
```

PS: There maybe no root elements (elements with 'parent' key = '')
PPS: Parent element may have more than 1-2 levels of children

Comment: I don't get it. What do yo mean with "parent-child way"? Or another question: what are you trying to accomplish? I'm pretty sure you could use a tree to get rid of these problems…

Comment: I'm getting the first list as a result of a SQL query. Then it is being passed to a template in order to build a table. Template uses list elements to create table's rows. What I need now - it to rearrange this list in a way the resulting table would have an hierarchy, thus parent-child way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with a straight sort, first build a tree from your list. You need two informations: the list of top nodes (either node with no parent or child with non existing parent) in the tree and the parent/children relation:

```
def build_tree(l):
    exists = set(map(lambda x : x['id'], l))

    tops = []
    children = {}
    for e in l:
        parent = e['parent']
        if not parent:
            tops.append(e)
            continue

        parent = int(parent[1:])
        if parent not in exists:
            tops.append(e)
            continue

        if parent in children:
            children[parent].append(e)
        else:
            children[parent] = [ e ]

    return children, tops
```

Then do a depth-first traversal of that tree with a recursive function:

```
def build_list(children, top):
    l = [ top ]
    if top['id'] in children:
        for child in children[top['id']]:
            l += build_list(children, child)
    return l
```

The first function give you the children/relation structure while the second let you build a list for each possible top node.

Now you can sort your list using those two functions:

```
l = [{'parent': u'#5963','id': 5962},{'parent': u'','id': 5963},
{'parent': u'#5963', 'id': 5964}, {'parent': u'#5966', 'id': 5967},
{'parent': u'#5963','id': 5966}, {'parent': u'#5962','id': 5968} ]
children, tops = build_tree(l)
for top in tops:
    print build_list(children, top)
# outputs : [{'id': 5963, 'parent': u''}, {'id': 5962, 'parent': u'#5963'},
# {'id': 5968, 'parent': u'#5962'}, {'id': 5964, 'parent': u'#5963'},
# {'id': 5966, 'parent': u'#5963'}, {'id': 5967, 'parent': u'#5966'}]
```

If you remove the node 5963, that will give :

```
[{'id': 5962, 'parent': u'#5963'}, {'id': 5968, 'parent': u'#5962'}]
[{'id': 5964, 'parent': u'#5963'}]
[{'id': 5966, 'parent': u'#5963'}, {'id': 5967, 'parent': u'#5966'}]
```

Comment: What if there is no top node? (No dict with 'parent' key that equals '')

Comment: @konart my current code fails in this case, but what does the data looks like when there's "no parent"? is it because children reference non existing parents? or do you have loops in the parent/child relation?

Comment: Let's say we are talking about some time tracking system with tickets(one ticket = one task). Each task may have some sub-tasks. The top level task may be owned by one user, but sub-taks by someone else. When the owner of the top task requests tasks owned by him - he gets a list similar to the one in my question, but when the list is requested by the user who owns only sub-tasks the list he will see will be the same, except for the top task (top node in your code). So all dicts will have some parent, but there will be no single root.

Comment: @konart yeah... sure, but that sounds more like "multiple top nodes" than "no parents"

Comment: sorry, submitted by accident, but you got it right. If we 'cut' out the top node - we are gitting multiple top nodes

Comment: ...multiple top nodes, each of them with a parent, not in this list.